# Two-dimensional array initialization

Tags: c++, pointers

CASE1:

```
int nrows=5;
int ncols=10;
int **rowptr;
rowptr=new int*;
for(int rows=0;rows<nrows;rows++) {
  for(int cols=0;cols<ncols;cols++) {
    *rowptr=new int;
  }
}
```

CASE2:

```
int nrows=5;
int ncols=10;
int **rowptr;
for(int rows=0;rows<nrows;rows++) {
  rowptr=new int*;
  for(int cols=0;cols<ncols;cols++) {
    *rowptr=new int;
  }
}
```

I am able to insert and print values using both ways. What is the difference in initializations?

Comment: Why does not a single answer mention a 1D `std::vector` of dimension `N*M`? No stupid memory leaks. No pointers to pointers that try to represent arrays.

Answer (score 2):

> **What is the difference?**

`#1` just allocates memory enough to hold a integer pointer and not an array of integer pointers.
`#2` Causes a memory leak by just overwritting the memory allocation of the previous iteration.

> **I am able to insert and print values using both the ways**

Memory leaks and Undefined behaviors may not produce immediate observale erroneous results in your program but they sure are good cases of the ***[Murphy's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law)***.

The correct way to do this is:

```
int nrows = 5;
int ncols = 10;

//Allocate enough memory for an array of integer pointers
int **rowptr = new int*[nrows]; 

//loop through the array and create the second dimension
for (int i = 0;i < nrows;i++)
    rowptr[i] = new int[ncols];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a memory leak in both cases.

The proper way to initialize such a "2d" array is

```
int** arr = new int*[nrows];
for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
   arr[i] = new int[ncols];
```

Note however, that it isn't a 2d array as defined by C/C++. It may not, and probably will not, be consecutive in memory. Also, the assembly code for accessing members is different.

In your case, the accessing by indexing is equivalent to `*(*(arr+i)+j)`

And in the case of a 2d array it's `*(arr + N_COLS*i + j)` when `N_COLS` is a compile time constant.

If you want a true 2d array you should do something like this:

```
int (*arr)[N_COLS] = (int(*)[N_COLS])(new int[N_ROWS * N_COLS])
```

Comment: You are reassigning `rowptr` without deleteing it's previous contents.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use 1d array to manage 2d array

```
int **x = new int*[nrows];
x[0] = new int[nrows*ncols];
for (int i = 1; i < nrows; i++)
    x[i] = x[i-1] + ncols;

for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
        x[i][j] = 0;

delete [] x[0];
delete [] x;
```